# how to remove Yosemite installer?

Tags: upgrade, macos

I had begin the update and left it overbite for download, it downloaded completely but then failed. I started the download again and this time it had finished successfully but I didn't notice it and thought it had failed again so started the download again. When it downloaded about 3 GB I saw the Yosemite installer and upgraded. But now the second upgrade icon is still there. How do I remove it and its data?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, got it.

App Store -> Purchases -> Press Option and you will see cancel.